# Do not want the popup to close when pressing button inside of it

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am using a jquery popup that I found in this site to load up a popup div, http://istockphp.com/jquery/creating-popup-div-with-jquery/. 
I added a button inside the popup which executes some C# code. However when I click on that button the popup closes (however the code behind of the button fires up) and the next time i reopen the popup my fired up code is there. I can't seem to figure out how I can reload the popup without closing when I press the button. Any ideas? Thanks

```
jQuery(function ($) {

$(".topopup").click(function () {
    loading(); // loading
    setTimeout(function () { // then show popup, deley in .5 second
        loadPopup(); // function show popup
    }, 500); // .5 second
 //   return false;
});

$("#Button2").click(function () {
    loading(); // loading
    setTimeout(function () { // then show popup, deley in .5 second
        loadPopup(); // function show popup
    }, 500); // .5 second
    //   return false;
});


/* event for close the popup */
$("div.close").hover(
                function () {
                    $('span.ecs_tooltip').show();
                },
                function () {
                    $('span.ecs_tooltip').hide();
                }
            );

$("div.close").click(function () {
    disablePopup();  // function close pop up
});

$(this).keyup(function (event) {
    if (event.which == 27) { // 27 is 'Ecs' in the keyboard
        disablePopup();  // function close pop up
    }
});

$("div#backgroundPopup").click(function () {
    disablePopup();  // function close pop up
});

$('a.livebox').click(function () {
    alert('Hello World!');
    return false;
});

$("#Button1").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".topopup").offset().top
   }, 2000);
});

/************** start: functions. **************/
function loading() {
    $("div.loader").show();
}
function closeloading() {
    $("div.loader").fadeOut('normal');
}

var popupStatus = 0; // set value

function loadPopup() {
    if (popupStatus == 0) { // if value is 0, show popup
        closeloading(); // fadeout loading
        $("#toPopup").fadeIn(0500); // fadein popup div
        $("#backgroundPopup").css("opacity", "0.7"); // css opacity, supports IE7, IE8
        $("#backgroundPopup").fadeIn(0001);
        popupStatus = 1; // and set value to 1
    }
}

function disablePopup() {
    if (popupStatus == 1) { // if value is 1, close popup
        $("#toPopup").fadeOut("normal");
        $("#backgroundPopup").fadeOut("normal");
        popupStatus = 0;  // and set value to 0
    }
}
/************** end: functions. **************/
}); // jQuery End
```

Code behind

```
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Doing my stuff

}
```

Comment: Post your code so we can see what is going on.

Comment: Do an asynchronous postback, rather than a full page postback, possibly through the use of an `UpdatePanel`.

Comment: You posted a whole bunch of code, but you never actually showed how you're sending the postback, which is the relevant part.

Comment: The code behind is never going to get called by jquery, unless you post back to the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seemed to have missed the point on how basic forms and asp.net works.

If you remove the pop-up, and make the div visible, you have a basic form which post back to the server. When the server side processing is done, the page is reloaded with any neccesary changes.

Adding back in the fancy jquery stuff you are still doing the same thing, posting back to the server and re-loading the page.

You have a few options:

**Change the visibility status of your hidden div when the form is processed.** 
I would say this is the easiest option. Add `runat="server"` to the div to make it available to the code behind. You can then change the class or style of the div in your `Button2_Click` event. The problem with this approach is that is will go through the whole page unload, load cycle, which will be visible to your users.

**Use an update panel** 
Put an [update panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001.aspx) inside the div. This will enale a partial page postback and just the contents of the div will be updated and you won't need to make the div visible manually. This approach is fairly easy to implement. The downside is that there is a fair bit of overhead in using update panels.

**Page Methods or webservice & jquery**
Probably he most complicated implementation but in my opinin the best way to do it is with a page method (or web service) with jquery. [This article](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/) provides a good introduction to the approach. There are many other examples out there if you google "asp.net page methods"